# Why Universal links works on iOS 12, but doesn't work on iOS 13?

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links

[iOS 12.4.1 iPhone6s Plus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Rvlq.png)

[iOS 13.2.3 iPhone7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcH96.png)

Now, I have some problem about Universal Links, On iOS 12.4.1, It works, but on iOS 13.2.1, it doesn't work. I upload pictures. Help me!

Comment: Now, I have solve the problem, the server directory .well-know didn't put the AASA file， then both the recommend path adds file ,That's OK.

Answer (score 0):

Can your provide the setting ? The file is info.plist. Or this issues may be the cache for the browser, just open the browser with incognito mode to do testing.

Comment: Thanks, Associated Domains: applinks:cdn.***zhuandong.com, apple-app-site-association content "{
 "webcredentials": {
 "apps": ["ZCP2X94NQS.com.jtcf.ul"],
 "details": [{"appID": "ZCP****NQS.com.jtcf.ul", "path":["/*"], 
      {"appID": "ZCP****NQS.com.jtcf.jnr", "path":["/*"]}]
}

}
"